# What does WindowsFeatures do in the Unattend.xml file?

Tags: deployment, sccm

According to [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749548.aspx):

> WindowsFeatures specifies whether to show entry points for Internet Explorer, Media Center, Windows Media Player, and Windows Mail.

What is an "entry point"?  Is this the same effect as using the "Turn Windows features on or off" control panel?  Or whether it creates pinned taskbar items?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is functions similarly to "Turn Windows Features on or off". While not completely uninstalling the software, all "Entry Points", which is geek speak for *ways to run the program*, are hidden from view, so for all intents and purposes the software appears to not be installed, someone could at a later date use the GUI or Powershell to enable that Windows Feature.